# Выборка данных из двух таблиц Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблицы `dbo.application`, `dbo.action`,  `dbo.ogpo_dept`, `dbo.employees`

```
| ID | ins_name | action |     | ID | Name   |    
--------------------------     -------------      
| 1  | Аскар    | 21   |       | 21 | Стикер |    
| 2  | Шыназ    | 18   |       | 18 | Защита |
| 3  | Берик    | null |
| 4  | Берик    | 18   |

| ID | Name               |    | ID | FullName | dept_id |
---------------------------    ---------------------------
| 5  | Департамент продаж |    | 1  | Mike     | 5       |
```

**Запрос:**

```
select od.name as dept_name, e.Fullname, oac.name, COUNT(oa.id) total
from dbo.ogpo_dept od
inner join dbo.employees e on e.dept_id = od.id
inner join dbo.application oa on oa.dept_id = od.id
inner join dbo.action oac on oac.id = oa.[action]
Group By dept_name, e.Fullname, oac.name, oa.[action]
```

Запрос выводит список договоров агента только с акциями, а мне нужно чтобы возвращалась договора и без акции и с акциями. Как добавить без акции т.е с null.

```
| 3  | Берик    | null |
```

Ну в итоге результат должен быть:

```
| dept_name          | Fullname | name   | total |
--------------------------------------------------
|Департамент продаж  | Аскар    | Стикер | 591   |
|Головной офис       | Берик    | Защита | 54    |
|Головной офис       | Берик    | null   | 5     |
```

Comment: Подключайте таблицу акций через `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL), читайте про OUTER JOIN.

Comment: @ Visman, не получается через left join выполняется и висит долго

Comment: @Zhandos, да я понял после комментария Mark Shevchenko, что вопрос невнимательно прочитал.

Comment: @ Mark Shevchenko, через Left Join запрос висит

Comment: На представленном в вопросе наборе данных невозможно получить такой результат -> "Ну в итоге результат должень быть:"

Comment: @Visman, в моем запросе получаем только с акциями

Comment: + вы используете в запросе несуществующие поля для таблиц.

Comment: @Zhandos приведите пример запроса с left join, который вы пробовали выполнить.

Comment: @PashaPash,                                                                                   select od.name as dept_name, e.Fullname, oac.name, COUNT(oa.id) total
from dbo.ogpo_dept od
inner join dbo.employees e on e.dept_id = od.id
inner join dbo.application oa on oa.dept_id = od.id
left join dbo.action oac on oac.id = oa.[action]
Group By dept_name, e.Fullname, oac.name, oa.[action]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй LEFT OUTER JOIN там где нужно выводить NULL

```
select od.name as dept_name, e.Fullname, oac.name, COUNT(oa.id) total
from dbo.ogpo_dept od
left outer join dbo.employees e on e.dept_id = od.id
left outer join dbo.application oa on oa.dept_id = od.id
left outer join dbo.action oac on oac.id = oa.[action]
Group By dept_name, e.Fullname, oac.name, oa.[action]
```

Answer (score 5):

При составлении SQL запросов, получающих данные из нескольких таблиц часто возникает необходимость указать, в каких колонках NULL допустим, а в каких нет. Единственный способ решения проблемы - использование одной из разновидностей JOIN. Бывают LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, INNER JOIN и OUTER JOIN (левый, правый, внутренний и наружный). Разницу между ними проще понять визуально.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у топикастера "через left join выполняется и висит долго". очевидно, он знает про left join. красивая картинка, хоть и выглядит красиво, но конкретно в этом случае никак не поможет.

Comment: @ PashaPash, верно, я пробовал вместо inner join поставил left join